# drag an drop multiple items along with IDs using javascript

Tags: javascript, drag-and-drop

I need a javascript for drag and drop multiple items along with the item ID and the ID where item is dropped on. It should support both IE and Mozilla.

Answer (score 1):

You can also do it with JQuery. I'd never used JQuery before, and I needed a drag-and-drop functionality. It didn't take long to figure out how to use it.

You'll need to install [JQuery](http://www.jquery.com) and also [JQuery UI](http://jqueryui.com/) and then use the [Draggable](http://docs.jquery.com/UI/API/1.7/Draggable) and [Droppable](http://docs.jquery.com/UI/API/1.7/Droppable) plugins.

Answer (score 0):

this might help, a very good free library : [Drag & Drop for Images and Layers](http://www.walterzorn.com/dragdrop/dragdrop_e.htm)

but you should implement your own logic to support dropped item.